# Freenas permission denied when creating files - how to set permissions?

Tags: permissions, freenas

I am struggling with understanding permissions with FreeNAS.

I have a SMB share I would like to share with EVERYONE (it's just 1 box and my family). I want to enable read/write/execute for all users. How do I accomplish this without having to do a chmod? Possible?

Answer (score 4):

I am running FreeNAS as a VM.  My permissions were not sticking.

I went to the FreeNAS server and opened a shell.

Run `zfs list` to find the path.

```
cd /PATH
```

Find the directory that needs changing.

Since I didn't have anything in that directory I was able to use a `-R` in the following for recursive:

```
chown -R nobody:nogroup directory

ls -l # to verify
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to get out.

Worked perfectly.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  Getting a bit annoyed by this.  FreeNAS.... a way to have network address storage.... and yet you can't write anything to the drives.... Grrr!

Answer (score 2):

Set Authentication to Anonymous in **CIFS/SMB|Settings** and remove check from  "**Set read only**" checkbox when you create a share. That should do. Though in FreeNas you cannot always get away with GUI setup only. In that case you can run "chmod" from **Advanced|Command**.